# How to access RPM command line arguments in a scriptlet?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I want to make an RPM scriptlet more or less verbose depending on whether -v or -vv arguments are specified when running rpm. Is there a way to access the rpm command line arguments inside a scriptlet?

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way to find out -v or -vv, largely because RPM scriptlets are not expected to do user input or output. That hasn't stopped anyone from doing whatever they wish.

The other problem is that -v and -vv are solely rpm CLI options. Other installers like yum/dnf have different means to control verbosity.